# p:panel facet "options" with p:menu - Cannot set icon different to default "ui-icon-gear"

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

I've checked all PrimeFaces 6.x documentation and online as well on p:panel + facet "options" + p:menu and have tried facet "actions"/"header" along with "options", but I can't seem to either **change the icon** to the right of a p:panel with a facet "options" + p:menu **or to set a css class** to its generated anchor link.

Does anyone know how to apply either of those?

Screenshot #1:
[image: Panel Menu trigger icon gear]

Generated code:

```
<div id="myForm:formPanel" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all templateWidgetPanel" data-widget="widget_myForm_formPanel">
   <div id="myForm:formPanel_header" class="ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
       <span class="ui-panel-title">Menu Test</span>
       <a id="myForm:formPanel_menu" href="#" class="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default" title="Edit...">
           <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span>
       </a>
   </div>
   <div id="myForm:formPanel_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">Hola!</div>
</div>
```

Source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Panel Menu Icon</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form id="myForm" style="width: 30%">
            <p:panel header="Menu Test"
                     id="formPanel"
                     menuTitle="Edit..."
                     styleClass="templateWidgetPanel" >
                <f:facet name="options">
                    <p:menu id="formPanelMenu" styleClass="templateWidgetMenu">
                        <p:submenu label="Options.." styleClass="templateWidgetSubMenu">
                            <p:menuitem value="Menu #1"
                                        styleClass="templateWidgetSubMenuConfigure"
                                        target="_top"
                                        outcome="index.xhtml"
                                        icon="ui-icon-settings"/>
                            <p:menuitem value="Menu #2"
                                        styleClass="templateWidgetSubMenuConfigure"
                                        target="_top"
                                        outcome="index.xhtml"
                                        icon="ui-icon-settings"/>
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:menu>
                </f:facet>
                Hola!
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by creating the right selector that disables the default icon (it most likely includes `.ui-icon.ui-icon-gear` in it) and then in this selector set a different icon. Yes, it is (ab)using the ui-icon-gear class for this case, but it works

```
.templateWidgetPanel .ui-icon-gear {
    background-position: -224px -112px;
}
```

The css (all basic css, nothing PF specific) above changes it into a 'star' However...

[PrimeFaces panel](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml) also has the option to add custom actions to the panel (from the same showcase):

```
<p:panel id="custom" header="Custom Actions" style="margin-bottom:20px">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
            <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years..." />
        </h:panelGrid>

    <f:facet name="actions">
        <h:commandLink styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-help" />
        </h:commandLink>
        <h:commandLink styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-star" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

In which you can declare your own components and icons (star and help in the example above)

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, thanks for your suggestion!
It would be ideal if my intention was just to change the css on my (framework) side. The thing is that we develop a tool that clients use it for developing their products, so - and I didn't mention it - the purpose was to add a css class so that they can on their implementation declare this css class in their custom css file and do what they'd like. It is possible too like this using ".templateWidgetPanel .someChild", you are right.
I wanted to keep it as simple as possible, but I guess I will have to go with that.